# Why is a tcp receive supposed to work in loop?

Tags: tcp

I understand that we need loops to receive incoming messages because a tcp package might not carry the entire sent message.

But let's take a look at the while loop. We know that .recv is a blocking call meaning that it will wait until some kind of a message is collected or connection is broken. Then how come the break statement will ever be reached? If there is no data, .recv will wait until data comes. So why is this the way to receive data?

```
while(True):
        tmp = client_socket.recv(4096) 
        msg += tmp
        if len(tmp) == 0:
             break
```

For example, my code here receives all the data I need in one receive. But it loops back again and blocks at tmp = client_socket.recv(4096). So it never exits the loop and waits for an empty message.

Answer (score 0):

> If there is no data, .recv will wait until data comes.

`recv` will either block until more data are arrive **or until the connection gets closed** by the sender. Thus, if within your specific application protocol the message ends with the close of the connection then it will work.

Given that TCP connection setup can be costly many protocols don't send only a single message within a TCP connection. In this case you need to invest more efforts into reading the message. A common way is to send the message size up-front and then your code would not need to wait until the end of the connection but until you a specific amount of data got read.

Comment: What you say makes sense. Can you please take a look again, I attached my code. Does this mean the sender doesnt close the tcp connection?

Comment: @Doe: yes,  it looks like that the sender does not close the connection. On sender close `recv` would return with an empty result, i.e. `''` and you properly test for this. But again, if the server is supposed to close the TCP connection depends on the actual application protocol, so maybe the server is just waiting for more data from the client here.